# Installing 8.0.28 mysql on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: mysql

8.0.28 As its release date was only few days ago,I cannot install it because it is not in the official ubuntu repo yet. I cannot work out how to actually manually install it either. I have tried various guides on the internet but nothing I try seems to work. All I get is endless errors with one thing or another.

So does anyone know how to manually install version 8.0.28 on Ubuntu 20.04 ? Or know of any up to date repos I can add ?

EDIT

Errors are like these

```
dpkg -i libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

```
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient-dev.
(Reading database ... 165702 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient-dev (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libmysqlclient-dev:
 libmysqlclient-dev depends on libmysqlclient21 (= 8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04); however:
  Version of libmysqlclient21:amd64 on system is 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1.

dpkg: error processing package libmysqlclient-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libmysqlclient-dev
```

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

```
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client.
dpkg: considering removing mysql-client-8.0 in favour of mysql-community-client ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of mysql-client-8.0 (--auto-deconfigure will help):
 mysql-server-8.0 depends on mysql-client-8.0 (>= 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
  mysql-client-8.0 is to be removed.

dpkg: regarding mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb containing mysql-community-client:
 mysql-community-client conflicts with mysql-client-8.0
  mysql-client-8.0 (version 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing mysql-community-client
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

Terminal info as requested.

https://dpaste.com/3TSBXB26R

```
apt-cache policy mysql-client-8.0 mysql-community-client
```

```
mysql-client-8.0:
  Installed: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Candidate: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     8.0.19-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://nova.clouds.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
mysql-community-client:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

Comment: Chris, can you please let us know what are the guides you followed and what are the endless errors? If you provide us more information, it will be easier to assist you.

Comment: For example https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-latest-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

So I change "22" to "28".  I have tried all sorts of 8.0.28 packages, I just end up going down the rabbit hole all the time. 

.. and I cant post the errors as the post ends up to long :-\

Comment: Can you please add the text of the errors you received in the question?

Comment: ah ok done. It seems to constantly complain dependencies are missing, but if I try and install loads of other stuff, it then starts complaining about version conflicts and having to run the fix commands.. I really have no idea how install anything when it is not available in the normal apt-get command.

Comment: hmm.. let's a take a look at your terminal history. Share the output of `cat ~/.bash_history` using a pastebin like https://dpaste.com/.  Also, paste the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-client-8.0 mysql-community-client` in your question. Also, take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/suggested-edits/175602. To know more about formatting code in Ask Ubuntu, read this: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code.

Comment: This is the problem mostly, as this is the latest version I can download. 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 500

Comment: When it comes to running *specific versions* of MySQL, I have often found it much easier to rely on [a Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql). This gets you out of dependency spirals while also offering the luxury of a slightly less exploitable database 

Comment: @ChrisSwinson Follow these steps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install

Comment: The only version listed there is (mysql-apt-config_0.8.22-1_all.deb). I did see that page the other day but did not see the point in it. This was why I was trying to download them by various other links instead and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

Versions are available for download here
https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/

Answer (score 0):

just download and ready the specific version that you need

```
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8# 
DEBIAN/                                                       mysql-community-client-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
libmysqlclient21_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb                mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb                    mysql-community-server_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-common_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb                    mysql-community-server-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb
```

install with astrek  **

```
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8# dpkg -i mysql-c*



Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
(Reading database ... 239805 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-common_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client.
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-client_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client-core.
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-client-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client-core (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client-plugins.
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client-plugins (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) over (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server-core.
Preparing to unpack mysql-community-server-core_8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server-core (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up mysql-common (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-community-client-plugins (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server-core (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-client-core (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-client (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.28-1ubuntu20.04) ...
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service → /lib/systemd/system/mysql.service.
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
```

version check

```
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.28 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

service check

```
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8# systemctl status mysql.serv
mysql.server.service  mysql.service         
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8# systemctl status mysql.server.service 
● mysql.server.service - LSB: start and stop MySQL
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql.server; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Thu 2022-09-01 13:19:30 +04; 2h 3min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 9439)
     Memory: 0B
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.server.service

Sep 01 13:19:27 mytestserver systemd[1]: Starting LSB: start and stop MySQL...
Sep 01 13:19:27 mytestserver mysql.server[3066]: Starting MySQL
Sep 01 13:19:27 mytestserver mysql.server[3066]: .
Sep 01 13:19:27 mytestserver mysql.server[3096]: Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/mytestserver.err'.
Sep 01 13:19:30 mytestserver mysql.server[3066]: .. *
Sep 01 13:19:30 mytestserver systemd[1]: Started LSB: start and stop MySQL.
```

login check

```
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8# mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 10
Server version: 8.0.28 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2022, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.




mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> quit
Bye
root@mytestserver:/pkg/mysql8#
```

Comment: it seems like it *just worked* for you, unlike for the OP